# Animation for Qml Loader when loader.source changes

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qt5.4

Is there any way to apply animation when we change source of `Loader` component in QML?
For example suppose I have the following `Loader`:

```
Loader {
     anchors.fill: parent
     id: loader
}
```

I want an animation from left to right when I set `loader.source = "content.qml"`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Loader {
        id: loader
        onSourceChanged: animation.running = true

        NumberAnimation {
            id: animation
            target: loader.item
            property: "x"
            from: 0
            to: window.width - loader.item.width
            duration: 1000
            easing.type: Easing.InExpo
        }
    }

    // Replace this with some other action that changes the source.
    Component.onCompleted: loader.source = "MyRectangle.qml"
}
```

**MyRectangle.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    color: "red"
    width: 150
    height: 150
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, although it was not as nice as I thought it would be. It is not a neat approach to add animation to the loader component. It sometimes run faster and some other times slower and with annoying delay! Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could try changing `onSourceChanged` to `onStatusChanged` and only start the animation if the `status` is `Loader.Ready`? Without having code to reproduce the slowness, it's hard to offer more advice. You could paste a simplified (but still "heavy") version of the item loaded by the `Loader` so I can try it out.

Answer (score 4):

Is it mandatory to use a `Loader`?

If it's not, you can use a `StackView` (of course, having a depth of 1 if you don't want to offer a more complex navigation) and load your components by pushing them on the stack with the `replace` option set to true.

That said, you can obtain the result you are asking for as follows:

```
StackView {
    delegate: StackViewDelegate {
        function transitionFinished(properties) {
            properties.exitItem.x = 0
        }

        pushTransition: StackViewTransition {
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: enterItem
                property: "x"
                from: enterItem.width
                to: 0
            }

            PropertyAnimation {
                target: exitItem
                property: "x"
                from: 0
                to: -exitItem.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize if it doesn't work as is (even though it should), but I'm on a mobile phone and I cannot test it right now.

Comment: I can not use this alternative. I used the Loader component to create a custom Tab View. It's not possible to use Stack View in my case because I need to change only the Tab content not all of page. after all it was useful for someone who prefers stack view. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @a.toraby Even thought I'm late, simply don't make StackView the root element!

Comment: @skypjack StackView is not Asynchronus